# Getting the CNF and DNF (Logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a function:

$$A = \lnot \left(p \rightarrow \lnot(q\lor r)\right)$$

Simplifying it, the DNF of the Function is

$$(p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$$

How do I get the CNF of this function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back up to to where you were before obtaining the DNF form:

$$A = p \land (q \lor r)$$

There you are: CNF.

For a refresher on "what counts" as [Conjunctive Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Examples_and_counterexamples), see the given link for some nice examples.

I'm assuming you first did the following:

$$
\begin{align} \lnot[p \rightarrow \lnot (q \lor r) & \iff \lnot[\lnot p \lor \lnot(q \lor r)]\tag{1}\\ \\
& \iff \lnot\lnot p \land \lnot \lnot (q\lor r) \tag{2}\\ \\
& \iff p \land (q \lor r) \tag{3: CNF}
\end{align}
$$

And so to get your Disjunctive Normal Form, we just use the *distribute* law on $(3)$:

$$p \land (q \lor r) \iff (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)\tag{4: DNF}$$

Comment: +1 for my dear friend Amy. An sleeping one who are playing with Angels right now.

Comment: @amWhy: Just so very good at these! +1